# Dispatching redux-thunk actions without importing

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

In redux-saga we can run saga just like reducers. `dispatch({type: 'SAGA_GET_POSTS', payload: 'all'})` and also have `posts.sagas.js` for all posts related sagas.

Can we do the same with redux-thunk? So we dont have to import actions before dispatching them in components?

Comment: yes you have to import actions before dispatching

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't ***need*** to import action objects or action creators in order to use them.

1. You can simply manually dispatch action objects

   ```
   dispatch({ type: 'MY_ACTION', payload: 'payload' });
   ```
2. You can define an action creator locally and then dispatch

   ```
   const myAction = (data) => ({ type: 'MY_ACTION', payload: data });

   ...

   dispatch(myAction('payload'));
   ```

This obviously breaks reusability though, which is why action creators are typically defined in a "central" location and exported for use by *any* component in the app. If you only need it once however defining locally will work.

Comment: maybe I described my question incorrectly. I want to dispatch my action like this dispatch({ type: '_GET_POSTS', payload: 'payload' }); and in some file have all 'posts' related actions. I dont want to use dispatch(myAction('payload'));

Comment: @rendom That's exactly how dispatch works, it dispatches an action object to the store. An action creator is just a function that returns an action object. Two ways to accomplish the same thing. Can you clarify what you mean by "and in some file have all 'posts' related actions"?

Comment: in redux-saga we can have saga files like posts.sagas.js, auth.saga.js, and there we can have all our logic related to posts and auth. to call this we just use dispatch({ type: '_SAGA_GET_POSTS', payload: 'payload' }) for example. We are not importing any actions like myAction in your example. So my question was, Can we do something like this in redux-thunk?

Comment: @rendom Yes, like I said, you can manually dispatch any action object, or action creator result, to the redux store, basically regardless of it being imported or defined locally. If you want to define them locally or inline that's your call. Sagas, rxjs, redux-observables, redux-thunk.... these are just special middlewares that allow you to dispatch asynchronous actions to the store, and none of them care if the dispatched action object was imported from elsewhere or not.

Comment: but where can I declare my list of thunk actions?

Comment: @rendom I'm not sure I follow this question since you said you didn't want to declare any actions and wanted to dispatch action objects directly. Thunks are functions. You can declare them wherever you need them.